# Runway distance remaining signs outside of USA and/or in meters?

Tags: runways, airport-markings

1. Are there runway distance remaining signs used outside of the United States (and territories)?  From what I can tell by reading [this document](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2016/ACI/D2-03MarkingsSigns.pdf) (p. 50), these are [standardized by the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html) (§ 2-3-13), but not the ICAO.
2. Do these exist anywhere in SI units (e.g. meters)?

[image: Runway distance remaining sign]
Image from ICAO document linked above

Comment: I can't really provide a thorough answer, but they certainly do exist outside the USA. Here is one example from Aalborg (EKYT): https://skraafoto.dataforsyningen.dk/?orientation=east&center=551831.34128862%2C6328221.655&item=2021_81_08_4_0022_00001695 Interestingly, they are spaced by 1000 ft (not SI units). I think it may be a military thing - EKYT is a NATO airbase

Comment: And an example from Madeira (LPMA). Don't know what the spacing is here. https://www.airliners.net/photo/LTU-Lufttransport-Unternehmen/Airbus-A330-322/1127098/L

Answer (score 2):

There is no ICAO standard for runway distance remaining. Some nations have their own standards: for instance, Germany has a sign reading "½" in black on a yellow background at the halfway point.

[This EASA document](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/downloads/136287/en) indicates that:

> ICAO is currently working on the runway distance-remaining signs for which EASA is
> following the developments and will review the outcome of ICAO's work.